# Migrating local database from app_data folder to SQL Azure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure

I have a database in the app_data folder of an asp.net website on my local machine.  I'm now trying to migrate that database to SQL Azure using the [SQL Azure Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/).  Here's my issue.  The Migration Wizard only sees the databases that I have on my local sql server.  It does not see the database in my application's app_data folder and I can't figure out how to connect to it.  Is there a way to get the migration wizard to see this database? Or, is there an alternative way I can migrate this database?  I already tried scripting the database from within VS.  Unfortunately the script failed to execute on Azure because of differences in the way that SQL Azure & regular SQL Server work.  I know that from past experience the Migration Wizard resolves these differences easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run the script you created in VS on your local SQL Server to create the DB locally
2. Use the SQL Azure Migration Wizard to create the new script from the DB you created in 1.

or

1. Attach the DB in app_data as a SQL Server DB using SQL Server Management Studio
2. Use the SQL Azure Migration Wizard to create the new script from the DB you attached in 1.

Comment: Thanks.  That was easy...don't know why I didn't think of it.